# How to replace page animated with Navigator 2.0?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-widget

I'm navigating to another page by change of an item in the `pages` collection.

```
final page = ...
return Scaffold(
            body: Navigator(
              onPopPage: (Route<dynamic> route, dynamic result) {
                return route.didPop(result);
              },
              pages: [
                MaterialPage(child: page),
              ],
            ),
...
```

And there is no a transition animation in this case (on IOS at least). When I'm adding a page to the collection - animation present. But I don't need a pages stack. How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `key` parameter when you change the page.

Example:

```
final page = condition 
  ? MaterialPage(key: ValueKey('page1'), child: page1)
  : MaterialPage(key: ValueKey('page2'), child: page2);

return Scaffold(
            body: Navigator(
              onPopPage: (Route<dynamic> route, dynamic result) {
                return route.didPop(result);
              },
              pages: [
                page,
              ],
            ),
```